# URL Auto Appends path

Tags: browser

I have a problem in my URL in my browser.

If I type http://int-test.company.com/test.png

It automatically became http://int-test.company.com.company.com/test.png

But if I type using the host ip (for example 10.218.132.18/test.png) it works fine.

Also it only happens on one particular host name.

Have I configured something unknowingly in the browser settings?

Any idea why?

I've tried it in all browsers (IE, Google Chrome and Firefox) and encountered the same problem.

Thank you

Comment: Works for me: Firefox 15, Chrome 21, Safari 5.1.7, Opera 12. IE needs `http://int-test.company.com`.

Comment: i've also tried typing http:// or https:// but the result is the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect it's problem of your web server configuration rather than the browser. It probably contains some check that's supposed to redirect you to the canonical address, but the check is incorrect and adds the domain to URL that already contains it.

To check, have a chat with the server by hand. It's pretty easy. Take `netcat` (usually called just `nc`) or `telnet` or `putty`, direct them to the HTTP server port (using command like `telnet int-test.company.com 80` (`putty` is an exception -- it has configuration dialog)) and type in

```
GET /test.png HTTP/1.1
Host: int-test.company.com
```

and a blank line. If the answer starts with number begining with 3 (300 to 303) and contains line like

```
Location: http://int-test.company.com.company.com/test.png
```

than that's the problem. Get the server administrator to fix the configuration. Correct answer should begin with digit 2 and after few lines be followed by lot of garbage, which is what PNG file dumped to the console looks like.